# Driving the state of a discrete system to zero in one step

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

I have the following system of difference equations:

$\textbf{x}(k+1) = A \textbf{x}(k) + \textbf{b} u(k)$

where:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & \alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$ and, 
$\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

.. and am asked to find the values of $\alpha$ for which the state of the system can be driven to zero in just one step if $x(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{bmatrix}$

I have tried substituting $x(0)$ into $x(k)$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ into $x(k+1)$ to give me two equations. Whilst the first equation results in a contradiction, i.e. the $LHS \neq RHS$, the second equation gives me $\alpha = 0.5$. Is my method for determining $\alpha$ correct?

Comment: What is $\mathbf{u}(k)$?

Comment: The value is not given in the question, but from a semantic perspective, $u(k)$ is the control, a scalar, which provides magnitude to the control vector $b\mathbf{u}(k)$. Since it is not given I would assume it equals 1?

Comment: Surely $b$ is a scalar and $\mathbf{u}(k)$ is a vector? But note that $\mathbf{u}$ appears to evolve discretely just as $\mathbf{x}$ does since they both depend on $k$.

Comment: I edited the question as I noticed I typeset it incorrectly.

Comment: As long as $\alpha\neq 6$, $A$ is invertible and the equation $\mathbf{0} = A\mathbf{x} +u\mathbf{b}$ has a solution. Is that what you are after?

Comment: It could be. By setting $\alpha \neq 6$, you're ensuring that $Rank(A) = n$. The thing is I quoted the question as-is, so not sure if that would be an accepted answer and if we are getting the question correct.

Comment: @MPW Invertibility of $A$ is not required here and the condition $\alpha \neq 6$ does not really help either. Instead, $\alpha = 3$ is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a discrete system:

$x(k+1) = A x(k) + b u(k)$

where

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & \alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$ and
$b = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

and you want to find $u(k)$ such that $x(k + 1) = 0$ from the initial condition

$$
x(0) = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

So just insert everything:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & \alpha
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} u(k)
$$

Multiply these out you get:

$$
\begin{align}
u(k) - 3 &= 0 \\
u(k) - 2 \alpha + 3 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

So from the first equation we see that $u(k) = 3$. Insert that into the second equation you get:

$$
6 - 2\alpha = 0
$$

So you can see that your problem can be solved if and only if $\alpha = 3$.